# What does "to bite into something" mean?

Tags: meaning

The sentence I've met is "She bit into the sushi." Can anybody tell me, what does "bite into something" mean? What is the difference between "bite something " and "bite into something."?

Comment: There is no real difference. It sounds like she is savouring it, rather than just attacking it with her mouth.

Comment: Please never write "smth" on this site.

Comment: It means you "put" your teeth into food. It refers to the instant that occurs before you actually finish taking a bite. To take a bite, to bite into some food. If I bite your hand, I do have to bite into it first.

Comment: @tchrist - That needs to go into a post.  Please find a way to put it into a post somewhere, somehow.

Comment: "Bite something" example: I bit my cheek by accident, and I can't eat anything sour today.  "Bite into something" example: As he bit into the apple, the juices ran down his chin (thefreedictionary.com).  (It means to take a bite of the apple.)

Comment: I am a bit surprised that most of the (IMHO very useful)  questions about synonyms are closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bite means  to use your teeth to cut into something:

You usually use "into" to convey the idea of a deep bite as in

> - ***you bite into an  apple.***.

while  you

> - ***bite your  fingernails.***

Note also the idiomatic meaning of: 
***[bite into something:](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bite-into-sth)***

— phrasal verb 
​

> - to reduce something valuable:
>
>   - People are worried about inflation biting into their savings and investments.

Cambridge Dictionary